# Give option for user to still see browers version of website from mobile

Tags: mobile, user-interface

I have my mobile website built and hosted. I have written a script like below in .htacess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.m.abc.com [L]
```

But this will always redirect user to mobile website when he uses it from mobile. But I want a option for user to see browser based website also from mobile. How do I go about this?

Comment: Put a link to the browser web site at the bottom of the mobile web site? This is what some mobile websites such as Wikipedia do.

Comment: I will put the link. But when apache finds it as a mobile device it will redirect to mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the detection with a script to find if its a mobile device, lots of scripts [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)
Send to mobile site, then have the link at the bottom that goes to non mobile site, use something so it doesnt redirect back to mobile site again (cookie etc), save this choice, so the user gets the correct site if they return again.

Answer (score 0):

You should do following.

1. Remove above from HTAccess.
2. In index or default page of your website you need to check when if user is coming from mobile device?
3. If user is coming from mobile device redirect him to a demo page which gives option to user to redirect to m.abc.com or abc.com
4. you can do the same using javascript confirmation as well.

One script example based on device width...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobile.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Another based on device type...

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   location.replace("http://url-to-send-them/iphone.html");
}
-->
</script>
```

Based that i used...

```
if ( (screen.width < 1024) && (screen.height < 768) ) { 
window.location = 'http://mobile.site.com';
}
```

hope above helps